# C# Passing control reference to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button and hidden textbox on my main form. When I press the button it will hide the main form and show the second form. When I press the button on the second form I want to show the main form again but this time I need to show the hidden textbox. I know how to pass the text from a textbox to another form but not just the reference of the textbox.

Comment: winforms? asp.net?

Comment: winforms application

Comment: Create a public method in your first form to perform the task for you. Pass form1 to your second form. When you need to do the job, call that method of form1.

Comment: [forms are just classes](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/forms-are-just-classes/)

Answer (score 1):

You better pass the complete main form instance for the second form, and create a public function to set the textbox to visible, or create a property around it.
Something like:

```
//form1
Form2 second = new Form2(this);
}....
public void ShowTextBox()
{
    textbox1.Visible=true;
}
//form2
Form parent;
public Form2(Form _parent)
{
    parent=_parent;
}
///later
parent.Show();
parent.ShowTextBox();
```

Comment: You posted your answer 2 seconds before my comment ;)

Comment: Personally I hate passing a parent form reference to a dialog/sub/child.  Someday if you ever want to reuse that form elsewhere (and my, how often that happens), you've got a mess to refactor.  Events would be much better, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a custom event would be a better approach.  Have the secondary form expose an event, which is raised at whatever appropriate time (your button press).  In your main form, when you create your instance of your second form, subscribe to that event.  Then run your "unhide" code from within the mainform's event subscription.

This keeps the coupling down on the two forms and results in much more easily maintainable and extensible code (for best effect, use interfaces, but events are a good middle ground for learning).

Something like this:
(it's been a long time since I worked with winforms, or events even, so if this needs refining let me know)

```
// your secondary/popup form's class
public partial class Form2 : Form 
{

    // add a custom event
    public EventHandler<EventArgs> MyCustomEvent;

    // link up your button click event
    void InitializeComponent() {
        myButton.Click += myButtonClick;
    }

    // when your button is clicked, raise your custom event
    void myButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs, e) {
        onMyCustomEvent();
    }

    // this "broadcasts" the event
    void onMyCustomEvent() {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> h = MyCustomEvent;
        if (h != null) {
            h(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

}


// your main form's class
public partial class MainForm
{

    void InitializeComponent() {
        // ...
    }

    void showForm2() {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.MyCustomEvent += form2CustomEvent;
        form2.Show();
    }

    void form2CustomEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        myHiddenTextBox.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

All in all this is a much better approach in terms of code architecture.  Now the popup doesn't care who opens it (it has no reference to the main form), and the custom event (which is really what you're after) can be managed to any level of control you need, without interfering how other thing work (for example, perhaps later you may want to have a different action that fires this same custom event...)

Food for thought.